# how to transfer wordpress sql/database from local to live

Tags: database, wordpress

So for backing up any/all my WordPress sites i use a tool called "BACKUP BUDDY" and its
a great tool and all but lately its been really buggy and today finally it went kaboom!

Usually my workflow is that i develop the site on my local machine using WAMP/MAMP.
when done and ready for testing i use the tool, move it to my personal test server to test and when happy and work is approved, i move to the real server.

Since my tool stopped working(uploads half the content) i decided to just do it manually by installing Wordpress first on the real webserver(done), Applying my theme(done),

then exporting the database sql from the local server(done), and thereafter importing it to the real server(done) and the 2xs that ive done it the site comes up blank.(outcome equals major fail!)

im assuming that something has to be changed/done in order for it to work but not sure what.

unlike a normal DB where i can talk to the info as normal, since WP is a CMS im assuming that it ties the info to the domain but again, i dont know how it 100% works...

Any ideas as to what im doing wrong? because as of now, if i cant do it like this, id have to manually create ALL the pages. Plus, if i was going to then move it from my real test server to final real destination then id have to manually redo it all again...

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you aren't doing anything wrong. It sounds like your particular workflow could be as follows.

1. Upload the contents of the site via `FTP`
2. Create & Import the database via `PHPMyAdmin`, changing any info in `wp-config.php`
3. Define the site url, in `wp-config.php` [See below]
4. [Use a tool to find & replace](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) any hard-coded site-urls that wordpress loves to use. [See below]

Example code:

Define site urls

```
    define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Find replace tool

Replace

```
http://localhost/
```

with

```
http://www.your-new-site.com/
```

That should be it. It's live!

Answer (score 1):

You can export it using phpMyAdmin and then use bigdump to import it. download bigdump from here and make sure you read the first note about the exporting process, found here
http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/

Answer (score 1):

here is a bash script you can use to automate this entire process for you: https://github.com/jplew/SyncDB